# Angular2 component initializing two times during routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, typescript1.8

Let me make you familiar with my code first and then the issue I am facing. Below is the code of my main routing `app.routes.ts`:

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    ...LoginRoutes,
    ...DashboardRoutes,
    {path:'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard]}
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes), [AuthGuard,AuthService, CanDeactivateGuard]
];
```

`DashboardRoutes` looks like:

```
export const DashboardRoutes = [
{
    path:'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children:[
        {path:'New', component:NewData, canActivate:[AuthGuard], canDeactivate:[CanDeactivateGuard]},
        {path:'SavedData', component:SavedData, canActivate:[AuthGuard]},
        {path:'NewIncentive', component:NewIncentive, canActivate:[AuthGuard]}
    ],
    canActivate:[AuthGuard]
}
];
```

Now when I navigates to the dashboard page, my dashboard component initializes, which is absolutely fine. But if I navigates on any child route component of dashboard, dashboard component initializes again; once only. My second concern is that when I am already declaring **Route** for **Deshbaord component** in `DashboardRoutes` then why I need to declare it again in `app.routes.ts`? If I removes its declaration from `app.routes.ts`, it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hard to tell. Please provide a Plunker.

Comment: Why do you use `{path:'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard]}` in `app.routes.ts` again?

Comment: @micronyks If I remove it, app stop working.

Answer (score 1):

Your dashboard component is being loaded twice because u have declared two times in your application ,once in app.routes and secondly in dashboard routes ... just declare it in dashboardroutes only and provide its link in app.routes as ..

> export const routes: RouterConfig = [
>       ...LoginRoutes,
>       ...DashboardRoutes];
>
> export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
>       provideRouter(routes), AuthGuard,AuthService, CanDeactivateGuard ]

this will resolve your both issues..

if still u got any query let us know :)

Comment: I I'll remove this declaration from app.routes, app stops working. app says Error: Cannot match any routes: 'dashboard'

Comment: all seems correct ... can u provide the plunkr for this ??

Comment: I tried to create plunkerk for Angular2, but couldn't get success.

Answer (score 0):

So finally I got the answer after doing some R&D.

Everyone of your were right who asked me to remove

```
{path:'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard]}
```

but If I was removing this line I was getting error: **Error: Cannot match any routes: 'dashboard.'**

It is because when route goes to http://localhost:3000/dashboard, it looks for further redirection string because we I have declared dashoard's children. When route don't find any string to redirect further and don't find anything for blank path it was throwing error. To resolve this issue I need to make one more Route entry for blank path in `DashboardRoutes`, and after changes, it looks like:

```
 export const DashboardRoutes = [
{
    path:'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children:[
        {path:''},
        {path:'New', component:NewData, canActivate:[AuthGuard], canDeactivate:[CanDeactivateGuard]},
        {path:'SavedData', component:SavedData, canActivate:[AuthGuard]},
        {path:'NewIncentive', component:NewIncentive, canActivate:[AuthGuard]}
    ],
    canActivate:[AuthGuard]
}
];
```

I got the idea to resolve this from https://plnkr.co/edit/QlMe6pMINxJGTdA3xm0B?p=preview

So idea behind the solution is, If there is some component with some child routing component, an entry in children array need to be made for blank path too.

I appreciate your help. Feel free to ask any question.